# Unable to install Xcode 4.5.2 in OS X El Capitan 10.11

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4.5, osx-elcapitan

I want to install Xcode 4.5.2 in OS running El Capitan 10.11. When I tried it's throwing:

> You can't use this version of the application "Xcode" with this version of OS X

Comment: I know you are trying to run Xcode 4 and not 5, but check if that works for you: https://medium.com/@iBoostUp/how-to-run-xcode-5-on-os-x-el-capitan-4cb920641d5a#.gqa7bskzv

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.5.2 is too old to run on `OS X El Capitan`. People are facing issues installing/running Xcode 6.x on `OS X El Capitan`. Xcode 4.5.2 is definitely not supported by Apple on new OS. You might want to migrate to latest (if not at least 6.x) version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Update [XCode 7.1 Download](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/) to version 7.1 via App Store (or Apple Developer website)

**The problem was an outdated XCode version**